# A simple inequality in probability theory

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

Denote by $\mathbb N$ the set of all positive integers.

Let $k \in \mathbb N,p \in (0,1)$,does the inequality

$(1 - p)^k+kp(1 - kp) \leq 1$

always hold?

---

This is certainly not something like a homework,actually I'm reading the book "Probability Theory:A Comprehensive Course",and I wish this inequality be true.

Comment: Try [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) on $(1-p)^k$

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Actually I translated the expansion of $(1-p)^k$ into $(1-p)^k$ :)

Comment: Have you tried lagrange multipliers? It looks like it's true for $p, k>0$, except possibly at the boundary of $p = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof by induction.
(For $k = 0$, we have $1+0 \leq 1  $.)
For $k = 1$, we have $1-p + p - p^2 \leq 1$ which is obviously true.
For the induction step,
$$ \begin{array}{} & (1-p)^{k+1} + (k+1)p\left( 1 - (k+1) p \right)&  \\
= & (1-p) \left[ (1-p)^k + kp(1-kp) \right] & + p - p^2 (k^2p + k + 1) \\
\leq & 1-p & +p - p^2 (k^2p + k + 1) \\
\leq & 1\end{array} $$

---

Note: Yes, $k=1$ also follows from the induction step after establishing $k=0$.
I wrote it out to get a sense of where the "additional" terms are coming from and how to deal with them.

Note: See Joriki's answer for $p \in [0,1]$, $k $ any non-negative real, with strict inequality if $ p \neq 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer again!

Comment: One of my friends had drawn the graph of $f$ with $f(k,p):=1-(1-p)^k-kp(1-kp)$ using Matlab,and your claim seems to be true :)

Answer (score 1):

An alternative proof using calculus: Let $f(p)=(1-p)^k+kp(1-kp)$.

At $p=0$, we have $f(0)=1$, and with $f'(p)=-k(1-p)^{k-1}+k-2k^2p$ we have $f'(0)=0$. Since $f''(p)=k(k-1)p^{k-2}-2k^2\le0$ on $[0,1]$, we have $f'(p)\le0$ on $[0,1]$, and thus $f(p)\le1$ on $[0,1]$.

The proof actually also works if we replace $1-kp$ by $1-\frac12kp$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @RH_L: You're welcome. I removed the detour through the logarithm, which wasn't actually necessary.

Comment: @joriki That's alright,thanks for your earnest!

Comment: @CalvinLin: I think your comment referred to the previous version of my answer, where I had a detour through the logarithm? That was only valid for $p\lt1$, since it used the series expansion of $\log(1-p)$, which is only valid for $p\lt1$. I don't think the inequality actually holds for all $p\gt1$, since $(1-p)^k$ dominates the rest of the terms for large $p$ if $k\gt2$.

Comment: Yes, I had a brain fart about how $(1-p)^k$ works when $p >1$. I agree that it doesn't hold for $p> 1$ for $k$ large enough. (Editing my answer to reflect that)